# How to access a the prototype object from within a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

How to access a the prototype object from within a constructor function ?

In the following Javascript code I have a Person constructor with two getter/setter functions, and a hydrate function defined inside it's prototype:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+          Person           +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ setFirstname( firstname ) +
+ getFirstname()            +
+ setLastname( lastname )   +
+ getLastname()             +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+     Person.prototype      +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ hydrate( person )         +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I'd like to call the hydrate() function from within the Person constructor, even though it makes no sense to me, it's like calling a method before the object is fully created, right? correct me if I'm wrong.
**Javascript code :**

```
function Person( person ) {
    var _firstname = '',
        _lastname ='';

    if ( person ) this.hydrate( person );

    function setFirstname( firstname ) {
        _firstname = firstname;
    }

    function getFirstname() {
        return _firstname;
    }

    function setLastname( lastname ) {
        _lastname = lastname;
    }

    function getLastname() {
        return _lastname;
    }

    this.setFirstname = setFirstname;
    this.getFirstname = getFirstname;

    this.setLastname = setLastname;
    this.getLastname = getLastname;
}

Person.prototype = {

    hydrate: function( person ) {
        this.setFirstname( person.firstname );
        this.setLastname( person.lastname );
    }

};


var john = new Person( {
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe"
} );
```

**Result :**

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: this.setFirstname is not a function

**Question:** How am I supposed to do that ? is that even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that I should've changed the position of where the hydrate() function is called, and put it all the way at bottom [right after making setFirstname() and setLastname() publicly available ], as follows :

```
function Person( person ) {
    var _firstname = '',
        _lastname ='';


    function setFirstname( firstname ) {
        _firstname = firstname;
    }

    function getFirstname() {
        return _firstname;
    }

    function setLastname( lastname ) {
        _lastname = lastname;
    }

    function getLastname() {
        return _lastname;
    }

    this.setFirstname = setFirstname;
    this.getFirstname = getFirstname;

    this.setLastname = setLastname;
    this.getLastname = getLastname;

    if ( person ) this.hydrate( person );

}

Person.prototype = {

    hydrate: function( person ) {
        this.setFirstname( person.firstname );
        this.setLastname( person.lastname );
    }

};


var john = new Person( {
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe"
} );
```

Comment: this.setFirstName = stuff is considered as a function expression so that it has to be defined first before being able to be called

Comment: @ngakak  Right, it is a function expression .